# how to obtain the value of an input field in an *ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, ngfor, 2-way-object-databinding

I need to obtain values from a series of inputs in an *ngFor loop. I tried using the name "(change)=addQty(qty,i)" I tried 2way binding but all the inputs ended up with the same value. I tried searching Google. In the code that follows I have stripped out some non-related code and classes.

```
<div *ngFor='let meal of meals; let i = index'>
  <div>
    <span>
      {{meal.mealName}} &emsp;
      <mat-icon>thumb_up</mat-icon> {{meal.dislike}} &nbsp;
      <mat-icon>thumb_down</mat-icon>{{meal.like}}
    </span>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div>
    {{meal.mealDesc}}
    <br> Price: {{meal.price1 | currency}} &emsp; Qty:
    <input class='number' type='number' name='qty' min=0 (change)=addQty(i)>
  </div>
</div>
```

If it is something simple I will be so embarrassed.

Comment: `Show more code, what addQty does, etc.

Comment: At the moment it console logs what is returned. When I passed back 'qty' it was undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the value of `change` event back to your controller, change your addQty to `addQty($event, i)` and in your controller `addQty(e, i)` then you can access it by `e.target.data` or `e.target.value`